# Input and Output in Java

Tags: java, input, output

I have been asked to create a simple input output code for a training exercise in a new job using Java. I am a complete novice with Java so therefore I have hit a bit of a wall. This is my current code...

```
import java.util.*;
  public class Task3
  {
  static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
              {
                    int Number1;
                    int Number2;
                    int Number3;
                    int Sum;
                   Number1= console.nextInt(); 
                   Number2= console.nextInt();
                   Number3= console.nextInt();
                    Volume = Number1 * Number2 + Number3 ;
              }

              System.out.printIn("Answer:" + Sum ) ;

        }
  }
```

Effectively I want this code to read 3 numbers as input from the user and then produce the sum of Number1 x Number2 + Number3 as output. I'm sure there are a few ways to do this but the way I have started above is the way we have been asked to do it. Any help would be much appreciated as I am keen to learn more about this and where I am having trouble... Thanks in advance, John

Comment: Get rid of the brackets around your `int` declarations, you're restricting scope. Or put the `println()` call within.

Comment: Where did the `Volume` variable come from?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you ask questions in the future, please include any error messages that you get. This helps save time in getting the answer you need because we won't have to guess what the problem is.

Comment: Yes get rid of the brackets, you have introduced a local scope which is not visible outside of the brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyJavaProgram
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        int number1 = console.nextInt();
        int number2 = console.nextInt();
        int number3 = console.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Volume = "+ ((number1 * number2) + number3));
    }
}
```

Changes from your code:

- Removed a set of brackets which were creating a local scope where `Sum` was defined, yet you were trying to use `Sum` outside of that local scope
- Variable defined as `Sum` but then referred to as `Volume`; I assume this was a copy & paste error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for adding three numbers. Program should be

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1= s.nextInt();
        int num2= s.nextInt();
        int num3= s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Sum= "+ (num1+ num2+num3));
        // or play any game with those variables here
    }
```

You are adding extra `{}` and variables without any use.Get rid off those.